# Pass arguments to Jade/Pug templates

Tags: javascript, html, pug, pugjs

I'm trying to pass the `title` variable into the `head` section of the `_layout.pug` file.  i can't see any way to achieve this neatly so have had to resort to pre-pending variables to the block:

```
//- _layout.pug
html
    head
        block headStuff
            title #{title}
```

```
//- main.pug
extends _layout

prepend headStuff
    -var title = 'The Positioning Schema'
```

Am I attacking this the wrong way?  Should this be a mixin?

Comment: You could have `title` contain a `block title`.

Comment: @Ryan What do you mean?  I'm at _day 1_ of learning Pug so I'm very sketchy on what can be done.

Comment: Well, right now your `head` contains a `block headStuff`. In the same way, your `title` can contain a `block title`, and you can replace that block with the desired title in inherited templates. (IIRC the syntax is `block title | The Positioning Schema`.)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, things like the title would be passed through as variables from whatever back end it's hooked up to (node, usually for me). If you're just using it to compile straight to static HTML without a back end, though, you should just be able to pass it to the layout in `block head`

layout.pug

```
html
  head
    //standard head stuff that applies to all pages
    block head
  body
    //generic layout stuff
    block content
```

main.pug

```
extends layout
block head
  title The main page

block content
  h1 This is the main page content
  p And more of it.
```

Comment: Thanks, I was specifically interested in passing arguments though.  The example is a trivial one, in practice it'll be generating `script` tags based on a value(s) passed in.

Comment: Got it. So are you using this without a back end language? That's generally where arguments would be getting passed from.

Comment: Aye, just Pug & vanilla JavaScript.